# Printing to a client printer from a web app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, printing

If I have a printer hooked directly to a pc (a kiosk with a printer), how would I go about creating the ability for a web page (.net web app) to print a jpg to the kiosks printer with no user intervention other than clicking a button on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you created an application that hosted the web browser control (rather than using a web browser directly) you could control the printing process much more directly.

(assuming using Windows + IE is possible)

here are some example articles that might help:

[Configure a WebBrowser Control](http://en.csharp-online.net/Configure_a_WebBrowser_Control)

[Using the Web Browser Control in your C# Applications](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/12/23/1330.aspx)

and the ever changing MSDN docs for the WebBrowser class, which has the Print method.

From the print method remarks: "You can use this method to implement a Print button similar to the one in Internet Explorer. This method prints the current document without requiring further user input."

Answer (score 8):

This has been asked several times already, and the result is always that you *can't* do it via normal web technologies (HTML + Javascript).  The best you can do is open the print dialog, and that is *by design*.  What you can do since you control the kiosks is create some kind of browser extension (like a flash object, .Net hosted control, java applet, etc) and make that available to your page, so that it handles the printing part for you.

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problems in 2 different ways:

1. Using ActiveX
2. Creating a protocol like myprint://PRINT_DATA

Answer (score 2):

The other comments cover a scenario where you want to print on the computer of the web browser.

However, if you want to print to a printer connected to the web server (ie, the machine running the web application), you can use regular C# printing with the following twist: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/184291/

In my context, my kiosk runs both the web server and the web browser, so that solved my problem.