# Printing into a particular printer on c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application in ASP.NET and c#. Is it possible to print in a particular printer attached to server for all print button click..??
 Ie, If one clicks print button on client machine, the print is taken on the printer attached with the server....

If anybody knows this pls help me..... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What type of document do you want to print? The server would need a way to execute an application and call the print command. 
There are a number of related questions on StackOverflow ->

Comment: i want to print a crystal report associated with my application

Comment: Look at this question. Basically you have to use software installed on the server to handle the printing.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206880/printing-to-a-specific-printer-from-a-web-app

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do something similar to what you described but it was far from easy.

When the user presses print the document requiring printing was written as a byte array to a database table that also had a "Printed" flag (false by default) and the name of the chosen printer.

On the server that hosted the database I built and added a windows service that polled the database table to see if there any documents on the table that had "Printed" set to false. If it found any it read the byte array and passed it on the the specified printer (setting the printed flag to true).

Problems

You have to give the service logon details with sufficient permissions to access the printer

Web services do not support the system.Printing or system.drawing.printing name spaces so I had to connect to the printer using TcpClient, the IP address of the printer and port 9100 (this is the default port for raw printing). I then passed the stream directly to the port. This worked but I only ever needed to print PDFs that my networked printer was able to support.

For more information on printing raw data see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091)

I don't recommend doing it exactly as I describe, but hopefully this might give you some ideas