# Can I set a specific printer for Javascript.window.print

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>
> - [Printing to a client printer from a web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206880/printing-to-a-specific-printer-from-a-web-app)
> - [Changing default printer in asp.net or javascript, is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384246/changing-default-printer-in-asp-net-or-javascript-is-this-possible)

I'm guessing that this can't be done but I'm going to throw it out there.

In my Zend Framework web app that will be run on an intranet using FF4 or Latest Chrome, I want to be able to have specific pages print to a printer that is not the default windows printer. The page will display a print report icon.

Has anyone any tricks or tips to how this can be done?

Comment: I would say let the computer operator decides what are the best printing facility available for him.

Comment: @Talha Ahmed Khan your comment is valid but your relying on the operator to choose the correct printer for the page and human error means that this may not always be the case.

Comment: The given "possible duplicates" are actually not at all duplicates. None of them are about using a given specific printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's impossible. If it is absolutely important to do that, you will have to develop a plugin that needs to be installed/trusted etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply I was thinking would be the case