# Changing default printer in asp.net or javascript, is this possible?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Printing to a specific printer from a web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206880/printing-to-a-specific-printer-from-a-web-app)

I have made a program, and its requirement is to print documents, please tell me is this possible that i can change the default printer on client side in asp.net or javascript, and is this possible to change the trays of printer as well, as i can see this is possible in applet, what to do in .net.
I want when default printer is changed, i will save it in database, and whenever that page will be opened, it will automaticaly select the default printer to that selected item. So is there any library required for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, this is not possible**. Try to think through all the ways that the ability to manipulate a printer or printer settings via a web site could be used maliciously.

Unless you're using an ActiveX control, or something like it, you can't even print without prompting the user first (where they would be able to change their printer manually).