# Automatic printing from web page (bypass print dialog)

Tags: asp.net, web, printing, telerik

I have a client requirement that when the print button is clicked (on the web page, not the browser) that the content be printed immediately, bypassing the print dialog. Yes, this assumes that the defaults are setup before hand.

I already know that this is a potential security concern. In fact, it's even stated on the Telerik documentation

> However there is no way to know the default or in fact any of the
>   available client printers as this would be a major security
>   vulnerability. That is why the print dialog would be always shown, so
>   that the user can select the desired printer and then click the Print
>   button.

source: [How to print report on client machine without showing the report](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/faq-print-client.html)

I realize that a plugin may be needed to accomplish this task. I've been pointed towards Scriptx from Meadroid but I'm still evaluating it and additionally, it seem to only support IE.

My question is, what can I do to satisfy the requirement of immediately sending content to the printer, bypassing the print dialog? It's fine if it's a plugin and fine if it requires licensing. But it must support IE, Chrome and FireFox.

Note: If it helps any, I'm working with the Telerik web report viewer.

Comment: i also ran into this problem few weeks back while working with telerik, what i would like to suggest is if the page is just simple html then you can use javascript to print the page

Comment: That still brings up the print dialog.

Comment: This will help you definitely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213660/html-javascript-one-click-print-no-dialogs    :)

Comment: No, that will only work for IE.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206880/printing-to-a-client-printer-from-a-web-app

Answer (score 0):

You could set the *web-server* to print the document, instead of the client.  Of course, you'd have to know what printer they want it printed at.

Comment: How would this print on the client side and not on the internal network where the server is located?

Comment: Sorry -- if you're not able to open a TCP connection from your web-server to the client's printer, this option will not work for you.  Your specifications didn't mention this, and I assumed an internal LAN environment.  My mistake.